# Salesforce Heroku not letting me in

Tags: heroku, salesforce

I'm having trouble trying to enter heroku with my account. Salesforce won't recognize my built-in authenticator. There is no way to recover it and I need to be able to use my account again. Please, if anyone can help me with this, I will be really thankful.

Comment: What is "my built-in authenticator"? In any case, this is a support issue and [those are off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question for Heroku's own support people and [is therefore off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577)